# JSON PHP Results next page

Tags: php, json

How can i make a link to go to next page if i had more results??
I think it have to be a if [TotalPages] == +1  else echo.... but i dont know. sorry :-(  Here is the Json Array of the Results!

```html
Array ( 
    [ProductsSummary] => Array ( 
        [Records] => 20 
        [TotalRecords] => 41 
        [TotalPages] => 3 
        [CurrentPage] => 1 
    ) 
    [Products]
```

Comment: google php pagination

Comment: It would be something like `if($array['ProductsSummary']['TotalPages']){ // your link }` where `$array` is your original array. Just curious, are you trying to implement pagination here?

Comment: it´s a search engine. look here http://dateck-media.de/sf/searchform.php and search for " baby " it gives me 735440 results haha and now i want to create a code at the end, that gives me the numbers of pages , if one page had 20 results per page. but i dont know how! i´m not a pro

Comment: ok @Jeff i look !

Comment: I dont't find the right. I am too stupid haha sorry